# Stop two UILabel from overlapping each other

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

objectiveLabel.text = objectstring;
objectiveLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
objectiveLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[objectiveLabel sizeToFit];

vocabularyLabel.text = vocabularystring;
vocabularyLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
vocabularyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[vocabularyLabel sizeToFit];   


}
```

Can Someone point me to the right direction on how to get Label 1 to push or move Label 2  instead of overlapping?

Comment: You might find it easier to lay out UI in Interface Builder. Apple has some great tutorials on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "push or move" a UILabel, you just set the frames accordingly. So look at `objectiveLabel.frame`, add the `objectiveLabel.frame.origin.x` plus `objectiveLabel.frame.size.width`, and that's the minimum of what you should set `vocabularyLabel.frame.origin.x` to. If you want `vocabularyLabel` to adjust for the width of not only the `objectiveLabel` frame width, but actually to tweak according to how `objectstring` will be rendered in `objectiveLabel`, you calculate the size of `objectiveLabel`'s width by:

```
CGSize size1 = [objectstring sizeWithFont:objectiveLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:objectiveLabel.frame.size
                            lineBreakMode:objectiveLabel.contentMode];

CGRect frame2 = vocabularyLabel.frame;
frame2.origin.x = objectiveLabel.origin.x + size1.width;
vocabularyLabel.frame = frame2;
```

This won't factor in the `minimumFontSize` of the labels, though. But if the `minimumFontSize` is the same size as the font size, then you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called `Auto Layout`.

Comment: Is that available in current production versions of iOS?